# Create smaller backbuffer than screen size on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

Using FBOs to render off-screen is not an option because on my hardware (HTC Desire, Adreno 200) just switching a render target completely kills the framerate. This is a problem with all Adrenos (as seen  e.g. here: [Framebuffer FBO render to texture is very slow, using OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729352/framebuffer-fbo-render-to-texture-is-very-slow-using-opengl-es-2-0-on-android)).

So is it possible to have Android create a backbuffer smaller than the screen that gets automatically upscaled by the hardware to the full screen size on Present? Similar to how this works in DirectX?

I am using OpenGL ES 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the effect you want will be achieved by using surfaceHolder.setFixedSize().  This uses SurfaceFlinger to scale the surface of your Window to full screen size. On some Android devices this scaling will be done by the hardware compositor, so I'd recommend keeping the ratios between the drawn window size and the scaled size reasonable to try to avoid artifacts.

Comment: Thanks, it looks promising, I'll give it a try!